# UITableView and UICollectionView reloading won't properly work on main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I've been struggling with the problem for long and it's driving me crazy. 
I have some tableView and collectionView in different viewControllers of my application and all of them seem to have the same problem. The problem is when I reload them using the `[tableView/collectionView reloadData]` the data won't load in table or collection even though I've checked -using the code below- and I know that the app is not running in background.

```
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground || state == UIApplicationStateInactive)
{
    NSLog(@"app is running in background");
}
```

I searched for solutions and as one of them suggested I did as below:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self reload];
});
```

and

```
-(void)reload{
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.guestsArray count]; i++) {
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
}
```

by doing this the collectionView reloaded but the cell at indexpath 0 remain the same prototype cell in storyBoard until I scroll it.
here is the code for cell:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"gCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *imageStr = contDict[@"small_image"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageStr];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImageView *uiimg = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

        uiimg.clipsToBounds=YES;
        uiimg.layer.cornerRadius = uiimg.bounds.size.width/2.0f;
        [uiimg setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

    }];
    UIImageView *imageView2 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tik.png"];
    [imageView2 setImage:img];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Does it work correctly if you call `[self.collectionView reloadData];` or `[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];` inside your reload function?

Comment: ` [self.collectionView reloadData];` loads nothing and `[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]]; `   still has the mentioned problem.

Comment: The `-dataWithContentsOfURL:` method is synchronous.  Try moving the call to inside your operation block.

Comment: @johnnieb that works like a charm . Thank you so much.

Comment: @farnazusefi Please up vote my comment so that folks know that it the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @johnnieb sorry I'm new here and I think I don't have the permission to up vote a comment. please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In cellForItemAtIndexPath, mainQueue adds that block to the operation queue of the mainthread but does not guarantee when it will be executed. There could be other items in that queue still waiting to execute. Do you need that block there? I don't think it's necessary. Also, when people talk about "background threads" they aren't implying that your app is backgrounded, they are saying that you are doing work on a thread that isn't blocking the UI. That means UIApplicationState is definitely not the thing you're looking for here. I would keep

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self reload];
});
```

and you should be able to simply call reloadData inside the reload method body.